# AngularJS Group By with average

Tags: angularjs, grouping, average

I am working on a quiz that displays a radar graph once finished. The quiz has ~15 questions but the graph only has around 10 data points to display.

Some of the answers are grouped and then the average score returned for that group.

I need the data to return an array that matches the graph using 10 data points.

However as I have more then 10 questions I need to group and then average out the values.

*sort of logic I am thinking*

```
//group_average = question_score + question_score / question_score_group_array.length
//Score grouping is to be decided by a diagramGroupId property
X = (3 + 4) / 2
data: [7, 7, 7, X, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

I know I need to loop over the answers and then potentially group answers by the diagramGroupId, work out the average and then add back to the diagrams dataset array

This is inside my current controller onSubmit function

```
$scope.questions.forEach(function (q) {
    answers.push({
//Deal with the results of the quiz
'SurveyId': $scope.survey.Id, 
'QuestionId': q.Id, 
'Answered': q.Answered});

    // radar Diagram dataset 2
    userScoreTmp.push({'diagramGroupId': q.diagramGroupId, 'score': q.Answered});
    /*[
        {diagramGroupId:1, score:4},
        {diagramGroupId:2, score:3},
        {diagramGroupId:1, score:7},
        {diagramGroupId:3, score:4},
        {diagramGroupId:4, score:1},
        {diagramGroupId:5, score:4},
        {...}
      ]
      //which would turn into the following array if I converted it to an array
      [4,3,7,4,1,4]

      //I need the following (values grouped and sorted by diagramGroupId and then averaged)
      [7.5,3,4,1,4,...] */
  });
```

This is my Graph object (using [TC Angular ChartJS](http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/radar/))

```
  var labels = [];
  var optimum = [];

  $scope.radar.forEach(function (d) {
    labels.push(d.Name);
    optimum.push(d.Optimum);
  });

$scope.diagram = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        data: optimum //[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
      },
      {
        label: 'My Second dataset',
        fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
        data: usersData //could be something like [7, 2, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 7, 7]
      }
    ]
  };
```

JSON

```
//A single question object from my JSON file, contains 15-20 questions
questions: [{
  "Id" : 1,
  "Name" : "Question 1?",
  "Options" : [
    {
      "Id" : 1,
      "Name" : "Yes",
      "Score" : 7
    },
    {
      "Id" : 2,
      "Name" : "No",
      "Score" : 1
    },
    {
      "Id" : 1058,
      "Name" : "Unsure",
      "Score" : 3
    }
  ],
  "QuestionType" : "radio",
  "Required" : true,
  "Handle" : "Q1",
  "diagramGroupId" : 1
}];

 // radar object, contains 10 objects
 // used to display the radar labels and initial dataset points 
"radar": [
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Question 1",
  "Optimum": 7
},
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Question 2",
  "Optimum": 7
},
{
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "Question 3",
  "Optimum": 7
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Where are these groups defined?

Comment: I currently have an array with ~15 values I need some of the values combined to create an average and then added to an array that displays a graph with only 10 values.

Comment: The Groups are currently defined within my question JSON data, I've assigned each question an diagramId that I can use to loop over when I review the data. I'll try to update the question to make that more obvious